# Is there any way to suppres the output of plot() command in Scilab

Tags: scilab

When we run a plot command in scilab Graphic window number 0 is opened

```
x=[1:2:10]
y=[1:2:10]
plot(x,y);
```

I dont want to open this window. How this can be done?

Can I change the name of scilab plot window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to want to export without opening the windows, it would be:

```
driver("PNG")
xinit(TMPDIR+"/foo.png")
plot3d()
xend()
```

Answer (score 3):

### Opening plot

The command plot is specifically for opening a plot window. So what are your further intentions if you don't want to open the plot window when giving a plot command.

### Setting the title

To set the title of the plot, you can type, after you issued the plot command:

```
plot(x,y);
title('Plot title');
```

To set the title of the window, you have to get a figure handle and set the figure_name

```
f = gcf(); //Get current figure and store the handle in f
f.figure_name='My First Window Title'
```

Comment: Thanks.. I want to show the plot in my Application. I dont want to pop-up a plot window from scilab. Sylvestre has provided me the answer.

Comment: No problem, just was guessing at the goal!